# Download html table when clicked on button

Tags: html

I am trying to download the contents in the html table. Can anyone help me download its contents when clicked on button. I tried with following code but not working.

```js
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
  var csv = [];
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [],
      cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);

    csv.push(row.join(","));
  }

  // Download CSV file
  alert('Hey')
  downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
  var csvFile;
  var downloadLink;

  // CSV file
  csvFile = new Blob([csv], {
    type: "text/csv"
  });

  // Download link
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  // File name
  downloadLink.download = filename;

  // Create a link to the file
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

  // Hide download link
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";

  // Add the link to DOM
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  // Click download link
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```html
<table border=1><button onclick="exportTableToCSV(\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th> sub_domain</th>
    <th> nReviews</th>
    <th> Ratings_e</th>
    <th> Text_e</th>
    <th> rn</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align=\ "right\"> 1</td>
    <td> a1</td>
    <td align=\ "right\"> 2</td>
    <td> 1, 2</td>
    <td> asd, dfdsf</td>

    <td align="left"> 1</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML `<td align=\ "right\"> 1</td>`

Comment: You need to remove the backslashes in the html and javascript

Comment: you have to use datatable for these type of task .

Answer (score 0):

The filename given format is the issue.

You can replace the button code as follows.

```
<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('members.csv');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>
```

```js
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
  var csv = [];
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [],
      cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);

    csv.push(row.join(","));
  }

  // Download CSV file
  alert('Hey')
  downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
  var csvFile;
  var downloadLink;

  // CSV file
  csvFile = new Blob([csv], {
    type: "text/csv"
  });

  // Download link
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  // File name
  downloadLink.download = filename;

  // Create a link to the file
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

  // Hide download link
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";

  // Add the link to DOM
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  // Click download link
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```html
<body>
<table border=1>
<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('members.csv');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th> sub_domain</th>
    <th> nReviews</th>
    <th> Ratings_e</th>
    <th> Text_e</th>
    <th> rn</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align=\ "right\"> 1</td>
    <td> a1</td>
    <td align=\ "right\"> 2</td>
    <td> 1, 2</td>
    <td> asd, dfdsf</td>
    <td align="left"> 1</td>

  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```